# Two pages with same page number

Tags: header-footer

So my title page and table of contents have same page number. How can I make their page number appear as consecutive numbers.

Comment: Without a code example, we have no idea what you are doing, and cannot offer much help.

Comment: Does your document by any chance contain `\pagenumbering` directives? If so, what do they say, and where are they placed? Do also please reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: Please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce the problem. For example, as long as you do not change the page numbering, the standard classes do not produce two pages with the same page number.

Comment: Without doing anything more bizarre than type plain text, pages have usually consecutive numbers in LaTeX documents. Therefore, you are doing something not so basic to force another result. Don't do whatever odd what you're doing to change the default format and the result will be fine at this respect.

Comment: @Fran one doesn't need to do something bizarre to get two page 1: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/647

Comment: Hyperref can use its own page counter, but you need `[hypertexnames=false]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  By definition any code is bizarre if you do not understand what it is for.  For instance, `\mainmatter`  is not at all a "strange" command,  but for a beginner  it may not be  obvious that this command reset the page counter.